# Unable to install Apache Kafka due to gradle lock

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm trying to build Apache Kafka cloned from [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka) using gradle. However when I run **./gradlew installAll** it fails with the following error message:

```
\* What went wrong:

Cannot lock buildSrc build lock as it has already been locked by this process
```

I have tried deleting the locks in **~/.gradle/caches** and even switching to older versions of gradle, but nothing seems to work. What's going on here and what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Running install instead of installAll fixed the issue, apparently installAll tries to build with multiple versions of Scala

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug which will be fixed as part of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7844